# How to find 2 points in line?

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems, angle

Say I have a circle. If I draw a line that touches the circle, this line is in fact drawn to a certain degree, like [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Sector_central_angle_arc.svg/1200px-Sector_central_angle_arc.svg.png) (line `OB`).
Say the circle's center point is at (0; 0) [the actual point doesn't matter], how do I retrieve the point coordinates, that is on the line, that touches the circle, by using the line's angle?

The start and end points don't matter. I just need 2 points anywhere on the line that is drawn.

Thanks!

### EDIT

I needed it for my JavaScript project. I eventually found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456783).

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: Are you interested only in a line that passes through the circle's center?

Comment: I'm only interested in 2 points' coordinates that are on this line.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, and I'm asking to try and understand it better. Is it this line in particular you're asking about, or are you trying to solve this problem in a general way? Can you provide more context for what you really want? Otherwise, the answer will just be, "learn trigonometry".

Comment: If you have the equations of the line and the circle, solving for the points of intersection is pretty easy (a quadratic equation).  Lines which intersect the circle only at one point are called *tangents* and lines which have two distinct points of intersection called *secants*.  That said, what you are asking needs clarification.

Answer (score 1):

One point is the center at $(0,0)$.  The slope of the line is $m=\tan \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle measured counterclockwise from the $x$ axis.  The line is then $y=x \tan \theta.$  Choose any two $x$ values and you have your points.